# How to write output from Task Scheduling in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have read the documentation, but I don't understand how to write the output if the task fails? I deliberately made a mistake in my task and copied it to the controller so that you can see the execution result.

The result is an error that is displayed. But when the task is executed through Task Scheduling, I get empty output to my email.

How to write the error output so that it would be present in the letter?

My kernel.php:

```
$schedule->call(new Load())->everyTenMinutes()->emailOutputOnFailure('myemail');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The emailOutputTo, emailOutputOnFailure, sendOutputTo, and
> appendOutputTo methods are exclusive to the command and exec methods.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#task-output

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I missed this clarification when I read the documentation. I migrated my command and now the output is coming in fine. Thank you =)